# What is the purpose of /drawable-v14 or /drawable-v11?

Tags: android-layout

I've seen that some Google's or other open source projects have resource directories like `/drawable-v14` or `/drawable-hdpi-v11`.

Now, I understand what this means: all devices with SDK larger or equal than v11/v14 should use these images.

But what is the purpose of this? Why and when should I use them? Why devices of HDPI resolution and SDK v11 should ever use images different than HDPI devices and SDK 10?

I just cannot see when I will ever use one image for SDK 10 and another for SDK 17, for example. Makes no sense to me.

As a side note, the usage of resources `/values-v{11/14/17}` is logical and has the practical benefit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be use in order to style your icons to the current UI guidelines on the given Android version.

Android has had a lot of evolution on its GUI style from its beginning. In Cupcake, icons had to show a 3D effect with a shadow. With ICS, there is more flat icons. And it will keep on changing with android 5 and more... (Let's watch the Google i/o 2014 to know more about it! ... by the way: its today!)

So basically you can stick to the GUI guidelines even from different Android versions. It's probably not the only use case but it is one of them.